# Python scripts in /usr/bin

Tags: python, unix, scripting

I'm writing a pretty basic application in python (it's only one file at the moment). My question is how do I get it so the python script is able to be run in /usr/bin without the .py extension?

For example, instead of running

```
python htswap.py args
```

from the directory where it currently is, I want to be able to cd to any directory and do

```
htswap args
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Simply strip off the `.py` extension by renaming the file. Then, you have to put the following line at the top of your file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

`env` is a little program that sets up the environment so that the right `python` interpreter is executed.

You also have to make your file executable, with the command

```
chmod a+x htswap
```

And dump it into `/usr/local/bin`. This is cleaner than `/usr/bin`, because the contents of that directory are usually managed by the operating system.

Comment: after much pain and near-death experiences, I suggest to use the  specific python version you develop for #!/usr/bin/env python<version-major>.<version-minor> (e.g. python2.4) instead. Better to have control of the python version is running the executable (at least for the cases I experienced, YMMV)

Comment: the shebang should point to whatever distribution of python you expect the script to run on; often this ships with the script itself.

Answer (score 15):

The first line of the file should be

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

You should remove the `.py` extension, and make the file executable, using

```
chmod ugo+x htswap
```

**EDIT:** [Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14637/thomas) points out correctly that such scripts should be placed in `/usr/local/bin` rather than in `/usr/bin`.  Please upvote his answer (at the expense of mine, perhaps.  Seven upvotes (as we speak) for this kind of stuff is ridiculous)

Comment: Yep that was it, I did this earlier and for some reason it didn't work, turns out I forgot the ! in the shebang

Answer (score 2):

Shebang?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Put that at the beginning of your file and you're set

Answer (score 1):

add `#!/usr/bin/env python` to the very top of `htswap.py` and rename `htswap.py` to `htswap` then do a command: `chmod +x htswap` to make htswap executable.

Answer (score 0):

I see in the official Python tutorials, http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html, that

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

is used just as the answers above suggest. Note that you can also use the following

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

This is the style you'll see for in shell scripts, like bash scripts. For example

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Seeing that the official tuts go with the first option that is probably your best bet. Consistency in code is something to strive for!

Comment: For reference, the first one is better because it's portable. Not every file system has the second option.